# Python - Finding word frequencies and string frequency with possible misspellings and saving as txt file or CSV

Tags: python, text, count, counter

What I'm trying to do is scrape text from pretty messy text files for specific words that sometimes have misspellings or characters that don't belong. I have been able to accomplish single words with exact spellings across multiple files in a directory, which is close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. The last thing is that I want to save this list with the counts of words and phrases into a text file, and not just print it as a summary, which is what my code does now.

If it's not possible to find close matches, that's okay, but that would be ideal.

Thanks for your help.

```
import os
from collections import Counter
import glob

def word_frequency(fileobj, words):
    """Build a Counter of specified words in fileobj"""
    # initialise the counter to 0 for each word
    ct = Counter(dict((w, 0) for w in words))
    file_words = (word for line in fileobj for word in line.split())
    filtered_words = (word for word in file_words if word in words)
    return Counter(filtered_words)


def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    """For each .txt file in a dir, count the specified words"""
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            ct = word_frequency(f, words)
            if action:
                action(filepath, ct)


def print_summary(filename, ct):
    words = sorted(ct.keys())
    counts = [str(ct[k]) for k in words]
    print('{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n\n'.format(
        filepath,
        ', '.join(words),
        ', '.join(counts)))


words = set(['JUSTICE', "policy payment", "payment", "annuity", "CYNTHEA" ])
count_words_in_dir('./', words, action=print_summary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import os
from collections import Counter
import glob
# def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
#     """For each .txt file in a dir, count the specified words"""
#     for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
#         with open(filepath) as f:
#             data = f.read()
#             for key,val in words.items():
#                 print("key is " + key + "\n")
#                 ct = data.count(key)
#                 words[key] = ct
#             if action:
#                 action(filepath, ct)
stdoutOrigin=sys.stdout 
sys.stdout = open("log.txt", "w")
              
def count_words_in_dir(dirpath, words, action=None):
    for filepath in glob.iglob(os.path.join("path", '*.txt')):
        with open(filepath) as f:
            data = f.read()
            for key,val in words.items():
                #print("key is " + key + "\n")
                ct = data.count(key)
                words[key] = ct
            if action:
                 action(filepath, words)


def print_summary(filepath, words):
    print(filepath)
    for key,val in sorted(words.items()):
        print('{0}:\t{1}'.format(
            key,
            val))




filepath = sys.argv[1]
keys = ["keyword",
"keyword"]
words = dict.fromkeys(keys,0)

count_words_in_dir(filepath, words, action=print_summary)

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=stdoutOrigin
```